# Put text and picture in a same page

Tags: floats

I want to put a word and a picture in a same page. word up pic down.
code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,colortbl,paralist,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=1cm, bottom=1cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm}
\centering
{\Huge {Text}}

\begin{figure}[!Hb]
\centering
\vskip 3.1cm
\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{../Pics/pic1.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This leads to two pages: [image][image]

When I remove the text the picture will be in the first page.

When I reduce the size of the picture to `scale=0.7` they will be in the same page

I want to put them together in a single page without further scaling.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why `.eps` format is used?

Comment: Do you need a caption to the picture?

Answer (score 2):

You've specified `H` as one of the placement options. But since you haven't loaded the `float` package (which defines the `H` option), LaTeX doesn't know what to do with it and therefore ignores it. LaTeX then only has `b` to work with, and that's why the "caption" and graph don't fit on one page.

The simplest solution, I think, is to drop the `b` option and to load the `float` package so that the `H` option can be processed. Depending on the size of the image file, you may also need to omit the instruction `\vskip 3.1cm` and/order change the graph's scale in order to make the "caption" and image fit on a page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption,float}
\usepackage[vmargin=1cm,hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} omit 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge Text
\end{center}
\vskip 3.1cm
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{../Pics/pic1.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the text to figure environment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,colortbl,paralist,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=1cm, bottom=1cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm}



\begin{figure}[!Hb]
\centering
{\Huge {Text}}

\vskip 3.1cm
\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{../Pics/pic1.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```